# How to get TFS environment variable in a custom activity.

Tags: tfs, ssis, tfsbuild

I am trying to build SSIS Package using TFS. For this I have followed the steps mentioned in [here](http://blog.justtfs.co.uk/2014/09/creating-ssis-packages-using-tfs-build.html).

I am getting a successful build. However, now I need to copy the output from my Binaries folder to the drop location set while creating the build definition.

For copying also I have tried to use [MoveDeployFiles](http://blog.justtfs.co.uk/2014/09/movedeployfiles-copy-file-activity-for.html) which is also mentioned in the above link.

The challenge is when I am using the TFS variables $(TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY) and $(TFS_DROPLOCATION) for copying the output. I am getting this error - Exception Message: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\$(TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY)\Bin\Development'. (type DirectoryNotFoundException).

Please help me on how can I get these TFS Variable values in this custom activity.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from the variable call. $TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY should be sufficient to call it. If you are using brackets for isolation then the $ goes on the inside.